# Enable or Disable a User on Local Computer

Tags: c#

To enable or disable a user on local computer, I am using the following snippet.

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry currentUser = localMachine.Children.Find(user, "Administrators");
currentUser.Invoke("AccountDisabled", new object[] { true });
currentUser.CommitChanges();
```

I am assigning user as a string. I am getting a "filepath not found error": Comexception Unhandled.

Is anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: I think the error is correct: path not found. Probably caused by WinNT:// I don't know what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: That's to specify windows domain system where I will be looking for users.

Comment: Do you think my code should work without WinNT:// ?

Comment: It's a protocol or path name? by using `XX://`(note the slash)  the windows will understand it as a protocol. If you use `xx\` it will be understand as path name. Also: I recommend concat it by using `Path.Combine()`.

Comment: Your code segment is incomplete.  You are using a variable `user` help to give a complete picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path.aspx) for `DirectoryEntry`:

> Connect to a user on a computer. For example, **"`WinNT://<domain name>/<computer name>/<user name>`"**. If you are connecting to a local computer, **"`WinNT://<computer name>/<user name>`"**.

So, your code to grab the user should be:

```
DirectoryEntry currentUser = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/" + user);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a machine-level context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   user.Enabled = false;
   user.Save();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
        DirectoryEntry local = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost");
        DirectoryEntry user = local.Children.Find(username);
        user.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", true);
        user.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Uniform Naming Convention i.e. use "\\" like this:

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:\\" + Environment.MachineName);
```